# sqlalchemy won't use username with ActiveDirectoryIntegrated?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, pyodbc

I'm trying to use an Azure Active Directory credential to connect to my database, but SqlAlchemy throws an error. Here is my code:

```
import sqlalchemy

connexion_str = sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    username="user@our.host.com",
    password="password",
    host="our-db.database.windows.net:1433",
    database="db-name",
    query={
        "driver": "ODBC DRIVER 17 for SQL Server",
        "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated",
    },
)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connexion_str)
engine.connect()
```

I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('FA002', "[FA002]
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Impossible
> d'utiliser l'option d'authentification 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'
> avec les options Utilisateur ou Mot de passe. (0) (SQLDriverConnect);
> [FA002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]Impossible d'utiliser l'option d'authentification
> 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated' avec les options Utilisateur ou Mot de
> passe. (0)") (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)

It's in French sorry, but this means that SqlAlchemy (or pyodbc?) won't use the 'username' or 'password' settings when used with 'ActiveDirectoryIntegrated'.

How can I connect to my DB using Azure AD credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect using an Azure Active Directory account username and password, You need to specify A**uthentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword** in the connection string.

Like this

```
server=Server;database=Database;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;
```

You can find more information here about using   [Azure Active Directory with the ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/using-azure-active-directory?view=sql-server-2017)